# Login credentials failed while installing Blackberry sdk5 in eclipse

Tags: blackberry, eclipse-plugin

I have Blackberry SDK 6 with eclipse.Now i am trying to install Blackberry SDK 5.For this
i clicked Help->Install New Softwares->Selected Sdk.After accepting terms and conditions it asking blackberry developers login details.Then i entered login details.But eclipse not accepting them.It show invalid login details dialog as in screen.I successfully login through Blackberry account through site but eclipse not accepting them why it is.
Thank You
[image]

Comment: You may have to work with RIM on this one... not sure any of us can tell you anything more than "make sure you are using the right userid/password."

Comment: with my username and password i successfully logged in rim site

Comment: @koti: I too face this issue sometimes.. you give exact username like yourname@hotmail.com and password and try and if then also dint work means **create a new login**.. no other way...